# Nginx + Php-FPM - upstream response is buffered

Tags: php, nginx, buffer

Running Wordpress on Nginx + Php-FPM. We are getting these kind of warning message in our error logs:

```
[warn] 25518#25518: *34774 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/5/01/0000000015 while reading upstream, client: 80.94.93.51, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:"
```

After reading several other threads about similar issues we have modified our configuration by adding `proxy_buffers` as seen below but this doesn't solve the issue.

```
   location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        proxy_buffers 16 16k;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
    }
```

Comment: 16*16K is not that much

Comment: Should I be using fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;fastcgi_buffers 32 16k; or it doesn't make a difference to proxy_buffers ?

Comment: That actually depends on your use case: 32*16K will still give you buffering to file, if soemthing is >512K

Comment: Buffering to file is not a bad thing all the time, you just don't want it for every small request

Comment: sorry my question was proxy_buffers vs fastcgi_buffers. Are these terms interchangeable ?

Comment: `fastcgi_buffers` is between nginx and PHP. `proxy_buffers` is between proxy and backend.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to nginx.conf or virtual-host config file context(**http**, **server**, **location**):

```
proxy_max_temp_file_size 10240m;
proxy_buffers 240 240k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 240k;
proxy_buffer_size 240k;
```

You can set the values by your situation, But they must have a balance with each other(dont use diffrent numbers for buffer directives).

I have the same problem, and test these configs for a script with heavy and long time IO, SQL and php process, and it works fine.